# Varnish Cache on Apache2, Cpanel

Tags: varnish

I'm running a Cpanel VPS with 5 sites on it. I would like to use Varnish Cache one site only.
Can anyone confirm this is possible?

http://www.varnish-cache.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a cPanel plugin for that: http://www.unixy.net/varnish

Cheers

Edit#0: @Chopper3. I was involved in beta testing but no compensation was involved.

Edit#1: @Praxis Micro, it costs ~$5/mo for non customers. It's definitely not free :). I'm still running on trial and I'm weighing my options (so far so good). The thing is it's much cheaper than Litespeed and is as fast. We'll see.

Comment: Is ther any reason I shouldn't assume this is spam and against our terms of use? please explain why this isn't spam or this message will be deleted.

Comment: @Chopper3, don't you think the link is topical? It covers:

1) Varnish
2) cPanel
3) It has the Varnish backend logic to make Varnish work with Apache+cPanel
4) Has a free trial (you could just get the config file and reuse it). No need to pay anything.

But by all means, please delete the entry if you don't think this is relevant.

Comment: It's totally relevant but are you connected to the organisation?

Comment: I assume it's only available to UNIXy customers?

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me about this, I'll leave it as it is but please be aware that it originally looked like spam, consider that in the future.

Comment: Unixy plugins works great

Answer (score 1):

Yes, however if all your sites listen on the same IP you'll need to add a check for the specific site you want to cache, and allow all other traffic automatically through to Apache.

The way I normally setup varnish is to leave Apache on port 80, put varnish on, say, 8090 and use a iptables `PREROUTING` route to redirect incoming traffic through varnish first. That way Apache (and your control panel) don't need any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

- Install varnish(from EPEL)
- Configure to listen new IP address, and proxy to your site
- Check varnish(open http://NEWIP/)
- Change DNS record to new IP

Comment: This works, but there is a way to install varnish on alive site without either changing IPs, DNS or Apache (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Praxis for whm/cpanel definitely Unixy varnish plugin is a good start - just beware of differences between unixy varnish implementation of varnish caching compared to varnish' default method of caching - differences outlined at http://vbtechsupport.com/33/ - very long read!